# How to define factories for a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through, factory-bot

I am new to testing and factory_girl, and I want to create factories using factory_girl for a has_many through association.
I have seen a lot of articles on the web, but couldn't see the best way to do it.
I have two models, `Widget` and `Feature`.
The associations are:

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widget_features
  has_many :widgets, :through => :widget_features
end
```

and

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widget_features
  has_many :features, :through => :widget_features
end
```

Till now, I have tried this:

1. In my **widget_feature_spec.rb**, I did this

> require 'spec_helper'
>
> ```
> describe WidgetFeature do
>
>   context "- METHOD - method_name " do
>     it "should do blah" do
>       widget = Factory.create(:widget)
>       10.times { |i| Factory.create(:feature, :widget_id => widget.id)}
>       result = WidgetFeature.method_name(widget.id)
>       # do all the checks and expectations now
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

and many factories are

```
Factory.define :feature do |f|
  f.name "Feature_name"
  f.description "Feature_description"
  f.association :widget
end
```

and

```
Factory.define :widget do |f|
  f.sequence(:title) {|n| "Widget_title#{n}"}
end
```

But autotest fails, giving this error:

> NoMethodError:undefined method `widget_id=' for #

Then, if I add

> f.widget_id Factory.create(:widget).id

to my Feature factories, I get this error,

> /factory_girl/factory.rb:334:in `factory_by_name': No such factory: widget (ArgumentError)

I don't know what to do. I believe I am not getting it right. What is the best way to create factories for such associations.
Should I create associations in `WidgetFeature` OR `Wigdet` and `Feature` ??

Comment: I'm assuming you have a widget_features join table that you're not showing us, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line:

```
10.times { |i| Factory.create(:feature, :widget_id => widget.id)}
```

into

```
10.times { |i| Factory.create(:feature, :widget => widget)}
```